# Symbols in startup.sh of Apache Tomcat

Tags: linux, shell, tomcat, daemon

I've been trying to make my own 'Daemon' java thread.

I couldn't quite get what I wanted, so I got curious about how Tomcat stays alive even
after I disconnect the ssh connection.

So I decided to poke around the Tomcat source files, to see if I could find 'the magic'. 
In startup.sh there are some weird looking things I tried to find on the Internet without luck.

in startup.sh

```
    # resolve links - $0 may be a softlink
PRG="$0"

while [ -h "$PRG" ] ; do
  ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
  link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
  if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then
    PRG="$link"
  else
    PRG=`dirname "$PRG"`/"$link"
  fi
done

PRGDIR=`dirname "$PRG"`
EXECUTABLE=catalina.sh

# Check that target executable exists
if $os400; then
  # -x will Only work on the os400 if the files are: 
  # 1. owned by the user
  # 2. owned by the PRIMARY group of the user
  # this will not work if the user belongs in secondary groups
  eval
else
  if [ ! -x "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" ]; then
    echo "Cannot find $PRGDIR/$EXECUTABLE"
    echo "The file is absent or does not have execute permission"
    echo "This file is needed to run this program"
    exit 1
  fi
fi 

exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" start "$@"
```

1. What is '$0' ?
2. What's '$@' ?

What do they do ?

**EDIT**
Perhaps this really doesn't have much to do with the OQ but I just wanted to share what I've found.
After analysing the source code of Apache Tomcat, I figured it out. I'm not sure if this is 
how Tomcat actually runs. 
What I wanted was something like a daemon process.
First you need a launcher written in java. From within the Launcher, make a process and exec("java yourDaemonToBe");
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the name of the shell-script you are running is `$0`, argv is found in the array `$@`, i.e. command line arguments for your script.

Comment: I see. Then those aren't the magic wand that keeps Tomcat alive ?
Unfortunately, shellscript is Greek to me, I'm sorry to ask but do you see anything that might do the trick? keeping tomcat alive.

Comment: no magic going on there, but scripts in bourne shell typically look a bit strange.since tomcat and other java programs typically start by adding a bunch of 'jar-files' to the classpath, and then start the jvm with an entry point (class with main-function), you will se this kind of setup for many java programs (maven,ant..)